# Rails validation errors not displaying in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

I have a rails model with some simple validations, such as detecting uniqueness of a field. However, when I go to save a record the validation does in fact trigger but the message is blank. Additionally, record.errors.messages is populated but record.errors.full_messages is a blank array.

Example:

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
    validates :name, presence: true
end

b = Book.new(author: 'me')
b.save!
D, [2023-06-07T19:03:14.831923 #16132] DEBUG -- :   TRANSACTION (0.5ms)  ROLLBACK
Traceback (most recent call last):
    1: from (irb):2
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: )
```

Also, if I investigate the record it looks like full_messages does not work

```
b.errors.messages
=> {:name=>["must be given"]}
b.errors.full_messages
=> []
```

I'm using Rails 7 console for debugging. I'm not sure if something changed with newer versions of rails, but as far as I can tell I've not found any documentation saying so. Has anyone run into a similar issue with displaying validations within rails?

Comment: You overwrote the full_messages method?

Comment: I did not overwrite the method. It's possible some gem did, which is/was my suspicion. I've removed any recent gems and the problem persists. Maybe there is a version conflict?

Comment: Maybe related to custom i18n messages you might have added?

Comment: Next up: dig in.  Set a debugger break right before you do b.errors.full_messages and step into it and keep digging.